# React Native - Navigation parameter reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having this problem, I want to run some function in a component, only when coming from X route. Right now I'm doing it with Redux, but I don't want to use Redux for this case.

I have component A:

```
const A = ({ shouldReset, setShouldReset }) => {
  useEffect((){
    if(shouldReset){
      reset();
      setShouldReset(false);
    }
  });

  const reset = () => {
    // some state changes here
  };
}
```

and from another part of the code I have this:

```
setShouldReset(true);
NavigationService.navigate('RouteY');
```

I wanted to do something like:

```
NavigationService.navigate('RouteY', { shouldReset: true });
```

But the problem is, once it goes through the useEffect, I have no way of setting this param back to false, so it goes into an infinite loop.

Is there any why to do this without using Redux?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the params in the use effect it should stop the loop

```
clearParams = () => {
    navigation.setParams({shouldReset: null})
  }

useEffect((){
    if(shouldReset){
      reset();
      setShouldReset(false);
      cleanParams();
    }
  });
```

Comment: I didn't know about setParams, I'll try it now

Answer (score 0):

useEffect needs a dependency, if you are not providing a dependency in useEffect it will always run on every render.

Something like this:

```
const A = ({ shouldReset, setShouldReset }) => {
  useEffect((){
    if(shouldReset){
      reset();
      setShouldReset(false);
    }
  }, [shouldReset]);

  const reset = () => {
    // some state changes here
  };
}
```

Otherwise it will update indefinitely.

Comment: Yeah but I want it to reset, because if I go to that screen again, since the param remains, it will compare true === true so it will not run the second time

Comment: In that case you should look into keeping that value in state.